# IS NULL performance issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

We are experiencing performance issues in the production environment related to the following query.

Which update are recommended here to increase the execution speed.

How can we change where part here without affecting the end result and which help to increase the speed. We have long list of roomid but just added few here. We should consider different roomid based on selected values in UI side.

Required all indexes are added there.

Thanks.

```
SELECT
          si.id
        , crc.id
        , dr.roomid
        , dr.roomname
        , d.id
        , d.name
        , c.id
        , c.fullname
FROM
          mdl_simplecertificate_issues si
          JOIN
                    mdl_simplecertificate s
                    ON
                              si.certificateid = s.id
          JOIN
                    mdl_course c
                    ON
                              c.id = s.course
          JOIN
                    mdl_user u
                    ON
                              u.id = si.userid
          JOIN
                    mdl_compliance_report_crondata crc
                    ON
                              crc.userid       = si.userid
                              AND crc.courseid = s.course
                              AND crc.courseid = c.id
          LEFT JOIN
                    mdl_department d
                    ON
                              d.id          = crc.departmentid
                              AND d.company = crc.companyid
          LEFT JOIN
                    mdl_department_room dr
                    ON
                              dr.departmentid  = crc.departmentid
                              AND dr.companyid = crc.companyid
WHERE
          (
                    dr.roomid IN(0
                               , 1092
                               , 1124
                               , 1187
                               , 1157
                               , 1159
                               , 1163
                               , 1126
                               , 1180
                               , 1181
                               , 620
                               , 1143
                               , 948
                               , 1131
                               , 1183
                               , 1052
                               , 621
                               , 1177)
                    OR dr.roomid IS NULL
          )
```

Comment: 2 separate queries and UNION ALL

Comment: Put `AND dr.roomid IN (...)` into the `ON` clause instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: @Barmar - A 3rd option, possibly the intended one:  `LEFT JOIN dr ON companyid... AND roomid IN (...) WHERE dr.roomid IS NULL`

Comment: @RickJames That only returns the rows that *aren't* matched. That would be used in the second query of the UNION that Akina suggested.

Comment: @Nitin -- Do you want rowids 1092, etc?  Do you want roomid 0?  Do you want all but 1092, etc?  What you wrote is something like "I want 0 or 1092(etc) or non-matching dept/company, which seems strange.

Comment: @Nitin -- Once we verify that the query does what it is supposed to do, we can discuss optimizations -- such as `UNION`.  (That would probably include phrasing the two `SELECTs` differently.  Oh, is `roomid` nullable??